# iText move to next page

Tags: itext

I am using itext to generate pdf files with images and with some description for that image.

I want to print one image and description of that image in one page.

For next image want to print in next page.By using itext how i can move to next page ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lot of way to do that. Simply what i understand from your question how to generate a new page in a Pdf Document. Algo will be like this

```
for each image{     
     /*manipulation logic for image and text goes here */     
     document.newPage();    
}
```

Do a checking for last time loop is iterated otherwise it will create additional blank page.

Comment: For iTextSharp Usage, its  document.NewPage();